# Setting a .gif on JButton in Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton, gif

I ve been experimenting some trouble trying to insert a .gif image on a JButton. I ve made a gif on photoshop and I set it as an Icon on a JButton. However, whenever I run the project and the Window containing that button appears, the gif starts to "twinkle" really fast. It appears and dissapears like if java were refreshing the screen in a matter of miliseconds. Why is that happening?

I do attach the .gif file in case it's needed, and the code as well.

```
jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

jPanel1.setLayout(null);

jButton1.setText("jButton1");

jButton1.setBorder(null);

jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);

jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);

jButton1.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alumnofi\\Desktop\\gif.gif"));


jButton1.setEnabled(false);

jPanel1.add(jButton1);

jButton1.setBounds(303, 233, 70, 60);
```

Thanks in advance  and sorry for my english :)

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/t7fhc7.gif]

Comment: The code where you attach the image to your JButton would help us in solving this problem. Don't think the gif is causing an issue.

Comment: I ve attached it now.